# bizarre scp behavior and not sure if my computer is hacked?

Tags: scp

I tried to copy a directory called httrack_get from my local directory to my ec2 instance and I got this bizarre output in return. What does it mean?

[image: screen of my terminal]

Comment: httrack_get does not contain those files

Comment: `... -r ec2-user@x.x.x.x:~/* httrack_get/`

Comment: Isn't the source supposed to come before the destination?

Comment: Changing the order of source and destination worked, but it is still sending my .bashrc etc. Isn't that odd?

Comment: No, since you copied them earlier. Remove the copies you made by accident.

Comment: Got it. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy httrack_get to ec2. You copied ec2-user's home directory to your local machine. You have the source and destination the wrong way around.